# legacy serial input devices/inputattach in recent kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can I still expect recent kernels / distributions to support serial legacy input devices out of the box?

Case in point: SUN Type 5 keyboard. These keyboards speak simple a serial protocol (inverted TTL levels) and apparently are supported by the sunkbd kernel module. For test purposes, I hooked such a keyboard up using a usb to serial adapter plus level inverter and I can see the raw output from the keyboard by hexdump'ing ttyUSB0.

Afer doing

sudo inputattach --sunkbd /dev/ttyUSB0

I was expecting the keyboard to be made available as an input device, visible in /dev/input. But that is not the case. I get the output

serio: Serial port ttyUSB0

In the kernel log, and that's that. Nothing else happens. Other options to inputattach such as --noinit and --always don't make any difference.

The sunkbd kernel module is autoloaded by the inputattach command, but shows as used by 0.

Should this still work in this day and age, and if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never mind, found the problem, so I can answer my own question: yes, that all still works in 5+ kernels. The problem in this instance was that the line from keyboard to system wasn't wired up properly, so hardware initialization failed (silently). The --noinit flag to inputattach has no effect, the driver still wants to initialize the keyboard correctly.